# Нахождение 2^500-1 и работа с большими числами в C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

на олимпиаде по программированию встретил задачу с возведением 2 в 500 степень -1. Это можно сделать с помощью длинной арифметики, но я бы хотел найти более простое решение. На примете есть создание нового типа данных(подскажите как сделать), либо BigInteger и читал на форумах, что object как исходник для всех типов может хранить любые значения, не знаю на сколько это правда, подскажите как это сделать. Либо другой путь решения. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если требуется вывести результат в десятичной СЧ, то в любом случае нужно использовать тот или иной вид длинной арифметики. Если, например, в двоичной, то всё сильно упрощается

Comment: требуется вывести в десятичной системе счисления

Comment: `BigInteger.Pow(2, 500) - 1`

Comment: Я полагаю, что это была задача не на длинную арифметику, а на подумать - что проще: 8 раз перемножить большие числа, или 470 раз большое число на 2. Я вот так сходу и не скажу, что быстрее.